# Joomla 2.5 cache issue

Tags: caching, joomla, browser-cache

my website in joomla 2.5 version, my website has cache problem in menu.

when i visit my about us page and then go to product page and some product purchase (add to cart), in product page cart has update means cart item zero to 1 showing, but now i have visit again about us page my cart still zero product. and then F5 on about us page cart updated.

means every page visit again, cart not update.

i think its a cache problem, but gzip, system cache, mod_mainmenu cache and also cache setting disable but still problem are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header("Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jun 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

and also

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE">
```

write in template/templatename/index.php